# How to receive datatable via WebService call in a silverlight application?

Tags: web-services, silverlight, serialization, datatable

I've created a WebMethod that I want to access using a Silverlight application. My problem is that the information I want to send is in the form of a datatable and Silverlight doesn't support System.Data.

This is how my WebMethod looks like so far.

```
[WebMethod]
    private string[,] ListAllUsers()
    {            
        UserUtility util = new UserUtility();
        var allUsers = util.GetAllUsers();
        string[,] data = new string[allUsers.Rows.Count,allUsers.Columns.Count];
        int r = 0;
        int c = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in allUsers.Rows)
        {
            r++;
            foreach (DataColumn column in allUsers.Columns)
            {
                c++;
                data[r, c] = Convert.ToString((row[column]));
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

I understand that some sort of serialization is involved? Would like to know the best way to get this information to my silverlight application so I can present them.

Comment: I know too little to answer, but I think there should be a way to serialize the data with a common practice. Hope someone better answers your question!

Comment: What do you mean by "information is in the form of a datatable"?  You want to return the dataColumn itself or it's content?

Comment: I think wardh is asking for the best practice method of sending a datatable through a web service. I'd like to know this too, is the best way to use a jagged array or is there some easier way to use datatables with a web service? Maybe some sort of generic XML-conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want you can try this http://chunktransporter.codeplex.com/ ...

Otherwise you can try to work with xml.linq...
Look if this can help you

---

### WebService

`<OperationContract()>

    <WebGet()>

    Function DoWork(ByVal param As String) As XElement`

> Execute XML Sql query (Retrieve XML results)
>
> "SELECT ('AlarmType' as 'Alarm/@Type','Description' as 'Alarm/@Description'
>         "from Table FOR XML PATH(''),type) FOR XML PATH('Alarms')"

`Dim cns As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.CS)

        Dim sql As String  = My.Settings.QMAlarmToTacitate

        Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cns)

        cns.Open()

        Dim result = sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar

        Dim s = result

        Dim res = (XElement.Parse(result))

        cns.Close()

        cns.Dispose()

        Return res`

---

### Silverlight App

`Dim wc As New WebClient

        AddHandler wc.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf DetailDw

        wc.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri("http://myservice.com/service.svc/MyFunction?param1=11111&param2=aaaaa&paramN=nnnn", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))`

`Private Sub DetailDw(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)

        If IsNothing(e.Error) Then

            Dim x As Xml.Linq.XElement = Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(e.Result)

End if`